# Post on facebook using url scheme

Tags: ios, facebook, url-scheme

I've looked over dozen or so posts on SO, and found no answer to my question

I am trying to post a status update via the native facebook app
I found this url scheme : `fb://publish/profile/me?text=foo` that was supposed to do it

Several times i tried

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://publish/profile/me?text=foo"]];
```

the first 3 or 4 times i tried, it opened the facebook app to the post update section, however foo was not present in the text.

then after a few more tries, the app only opened facebook app, never even reaching the update status section.

How can i open facebook app AND go to the update status section AND put "foo" in the status update text ?

Comment: You can't. And even if you could it is against Facebook Platform Policy. Use the share dialog instead..

Comment: How does viber do it then?
My facebook app opens when i click their "facebook" share

Comment: this is what the line is supposed to do btw, open the share dialog

Comment: Yes use the share dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: do i need to do the groosome login process first ? does the app call for login if i use this code ?

Comment: The app will do everything for you

Comment: please post your last few comments in an answer, i can accept it this way